# Evaluating time with python

Tags: python

I need to write a program that reads in seconds as input, and outputs the time in hours, minutes, and seconds using python.

```
seconds = int(input())
minutes = seconds // 60  
hours = minutes // 3600
seconds_left =  + (seconds - hours)

print(f'Hours: {hours}')
print(f'Minutes: {minutes}')
print(f'Seconds: {seconds_left}')
```

This is what I'm currently running and it's not getting the desired output. Question in mind uses 4000 as an input and outputs 1 hour, 6 min, and 40 seconds

Comment: There were additional statements while defining seconds_left but i deleted them while working because they didn't work

Comment: Are you sure that `hours = minutes // 3600`?

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `hours = seconds // 3600`, not `hours = minutes // 3600`

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind `seconds - hours`?

Comment: Consider using [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod): `hours, seconds = divmod(seconds, 3600); minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you divide to get (e.g.) the hours, you should also take the mod in order to just carry forward the remainder:

```
>>> seconds = 4000
>>> hours = seconds // 3600
>>> seconds = seconds % 3600
>>> minutes = seconds // 60
>>> seconds = seconds % 60
>>> hours, minutes, seconds
(1, 6, 40)
```

This is equivalent to multiplying the int quotient by the divisor and subtracting:

```
>>> seconds = 4000
>>> hours = seconds // 3600
>>> seconds -= hours * 3600
>>> minutes = seconds // 60
>>> seconds -= minutes * 60
>>> hours, minutes, seconds
(1, 6, 40)
```